# Rest API Search Results is not the same as the results returned by the search page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have A search rest API, when I run it through Share point Designer, i don't Get the Same Number if results as Returned by the Search page on the Share point site, I have tried Using different Source ids , also tried to use the default source id from results source but I always get the same results so i am not sure what I am doing wrong.
My Other Thought is, IS there a way to Get all the results From the Default search function Built in to Share-point?

```
 var ct = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(ct);

 var queryStr = ctx.DataProvider.get_currentQueryState().k;
 keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryStr);


 keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);  
 keywordQuery.set_enableSorting(true);                                  
 keywordQuery.set_sourceId=("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx");  
 keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(500);


 keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);

 var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(ct);
 var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);


   ct.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);

   function onQuerySuccess() 
      {
      results.m_value.ResultTables[1].ResultRows.forEach(function (row)
      {
       var Aname1 = row.name;
       console.log(row);
                if (!$isNull(Aname1))

           {

           var name= Aname1;
               console.log(name);

           }


      });



      }



       function onQueryFail() 
       {

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the results are paginated. What it means is that, instead of returning all the results at once, they are divided into parts and each part (page) is sent once.

For example, when you search in google.com, instead of returning all 1,50,00,000.... results, Google returns only 10 results or so. To get the next 10 results, you click the next button in the pagination menu at the bottom of the page.

This is done so that the API and network don't get overloaded. Imagine how large a response with 1,50,00,000 records would be.

This is what's happening with you. In the response you recieved, see if there's a record with a URL for the next page, Microsoft usually does things this way. If you call that URL, you'll get the next page. If that's not there, see if the URL you called has a parameter somewhere, where you can select the page.

Comment: Hi, Thank you For the response, thank you for the clarification, But is there a way to get all of the results Using the search Function Above, I looked into the Rows in the  table returned, I could not Identify a conman Unique Identifier,  But there seems ti be no Clear explanation to why the function above is behaving the way it is.

Comment: @user5711432 I don't think you can get all the results, they are limited that way. Need more information to confirm though. Can you post the results you got, and details about the API for more clarity? I got to go sleep now, but I'll check again in the morning.

Comment: Hello, I could not really find anything in The URL that would be Considered unique or a record #. Also Different searches bring back different results. not all searches bring back consistent results. so I am sure that the default search built in to the site is doing a lot more than what I have.